# Unable to start Threading in IIS7

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis-7

I am running and executing the following piece of code in Visual Studio 2010

```
Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate {
                    Init(visible);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(this);                
                }));
       thrd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       thrd.Start();
```

This thread successfully executes, calls the 'Init' function to  start a new webbrowser.

However, when i configure the website in IIS7 with ASP.NET 4.0 App Pool, what ever is placed in the thread is not getting executed. Can some some guide me, what are the settings need to be done?

Regards,
Anil

Update: 
This is the link to the code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET

And looks like I am not the only one with this issue.

Comment: You cannot start a Windows Application within IIS. What do you try to do? And I suppose you already have the thrd.Start(); somewhere in your code.

Comment: How precisely did you establish that whatever is placed in the thread is not getting executed? (As opposed to, for example, executing but failing.)

Comment: I simply put a System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox both inside and outside of the thread. When it is outside of the thread, the page throws an error, saying It cant open the messagebox on server side (which is acctually correct) and when it is in the thread, nothing happens, no error and no MessageBox.

Comment: Right, so it likely did execute and failed. It failed to report it failed as well. If you put an operation in the thread that cannot fail, you'll likely see that it is being executed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Maybe, what you said is true, but I still dont get, why it would perfectly work fine in Visual Studio debug mode, but not in IIS7.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Your right, the Thread is running, I just confirmed. its the starting of new form where nothing is happening, when hosted in IIS.